# Nested pages subroutes with go_router (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

My app structure can be like this:

```
home/folder/:fid/player
home/folder/:fid/folder/:fid/player
home/folder/:fid/folder/:fid/folder/:fid/player
```

with nested folders that can open other folders (a folder can contain an audio file which plays in the player) etc

Is this possible with go router?
I've tried to do something like this instead:

```
home/folder/:fid/folder2/:f2id/player
```

but it is getting very messy. My router currently looks like this

```
 final router = GoRouter(
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
            path: HomePath,
            builder: (context, state) => HomeWrapperWidget(),
            routes: [
              GoRoute(
                path: 'session/:sid',
                routes: [
                  GoRoute(
                    path: 'player',
                    pageBuilder: (context, state) =>
                        getPlayerMaterialPage(state),
                  )
                ],
                pageBuilder: (context, state) =>
                    getSessionOptionsMaterialPage(state),
              ),
              GoRoute(
                path: 'folder/:fid',
                routes: [
                  GoRoute(
                    path: 'folder2/:f2id',
                    routes: [
                      GoRoute(
                        path: 'folder3/:f3id',
                        pageBuilder: (context, state) => getFolderMaterialPage(state),
                      ),
                    ],
                    pageBuilder: (context, state) =>
                        getFolderMaterialPage(state),
                  ),
                ],
                pageBuilder: (context, state) => getFolderMaterialPage(state),
              ),
              ...
            ]),
      ],
    );
```

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: Nope, I don't think it's possible so I stuck with the above solution. Alternatively I guess you could try to dynamically build the tree.

Comment: thank you for the reply. https://pub.dev/packages/go_router_prototype is under development and could be our solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably just "opinion based" and not a good fit for a site, but I think such things should not be done with a router.

The router is for navigation between pages. The app should have the only one page(route) `folder` that accepts the parameter `fid` and displays the content of the specific folder in the file system according to its value.

Instead of relying on the `go_router` stack of routes, a stack of `fids` should be created.